# c# operator definition only available on abstract class

Tags: c#

Please help me to understand why c# doesn't allow an actual class to have an operator or what I might be doing in the definition of my class.

The call to the create an Errd works because it is an abstract class.
But can you/ why can't you also have an operator in an actual class as in the remarked out version of my Errd definition?

Is there something in the remarked out version of Errd I could fix to make the `Errd errd = eq;` work?

I guess I should add the IDE error.
When Errd is not defined as an abstract the IDE becrys "

> cannot implicitly convert Eq to Errd.  An explicit conversion exists. 
>   Are you missing a cast?)

But an Eq is nothing like an Errd for a cast would not make sense.

```
Eq eq = new Eq();
Copa copa = new Copa(eq);
Errd errd = eq;

public class Copa {
    public Copa(Eq e) {
        //.. do something
    }
}

public class Erd : Errd { .... }
public adstract class Errd {
        public static implicit operator(Eq e) {
            Erd q = new Erd();
            //.. do something
            return q;
        }
}

/*
public class Errd {
        public static implicit operator(Eq e) {
            Errd q = new Errd();
            //.. do something
            return q;
        }
}
*/
```

Thanks for your considerate response.

Comment: Because you have 2 types with the exact same name (`Errd` and `Errd`)?? If that is not it then update your code as it is really hard to see what you are trying to accomplish with the above, at the very least make it compile. Also if you are receiving an error or an exception it would help if you included that information.

Comment: The second definition of Errd is commented out.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). See also section [Overriding Operator ==](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) and make sure your syntax is correct (it is not).

Comment: Turns out @Guillaume CR noticed my issue form the code I'd supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the type of the class you want to overload the implicit cast to. In your example, it would look something like this:

```
    public static implicit operator Errd(Eq e)
```

Note the Errd.

See [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) for details on overloading explicit and implicit casting.

Comment: Oh Man really?!?!  You are correct & my bad.  In fact there is a little red-squiggly where the name of the constructor is missing.  The squiggly was just to small for me to notice.